# how garbage collector in php handles sessions stored in a directory other than "/tmp" (default)?

Tags: php, garbage-collection

If I use PHP's session.save_path() to specify a location where the session data are to be stored,doing so,how PHP garbage collector handles this custom path? or does garbage collector always targets the default "/tmp" folder? To delete inactive session files stored in custom path other than /tmp,should I have to write code myself or PHP handles it? Please help